# PCM raw data into user space

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, pcm, alsa

I have the following setup: an imx28 running 2.6.34 kernel. The SAIF interface is connected to the PCM output of an Cinterion modem. I want to export the PCM raw data to userspace in something like a character driver. Do you have any ideas regarding the implementation?

Comment: *"Do you have any ideas regarding the implementation?"* is kind of vague. Maybe you should go into some more detail about what you are having trouble with?

Comment: So, mxs-dai.c is the driver for the SAIF interface. In the kernel implementation, the saif driver is connected to the sgtl5000 audio codec. My ideea is to build a character driver on top of mxs-dai and use the struct snd_soc_dai_ops mxs_saif_dai_ops to communicate with the SAIF interface. Is this the correct aproach?

Answer (score 1):

The "correct approach" is probably to make an ALSA driver, and access the PCM data through the ALSA driver. Then the device appears as a sound device, and the PCM data can be accessed by any ALSA audio program, such as arecord.

Advantages:

- You're using the standard API for sound data, so your device can be accessed by the many existing audio tools. And conversely, the userspace program you write will work with other audio devices.
- The driver should provide the relevant details about the PCM sample rates and data format, so it works easily for audio programs.

The i.MX28 ALSA drivers use the ASoC architecture. See the `Documentation/sound/alsa/soc` directory in the Linux source.

P.S.: I see you've asked a [follow-on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740507/alsa-with-pcm-interface-from-modem) which indicates you're heading in the ALSA ASoC direction.

Comment: Can I make modification to ALSA files to support PCM communication for Voice IC Si3228x, since I have not been able to find any support anywhere.